# How to validate a Sitecore Single-Line text field to include a character limit

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I want a maximum length for a single-line text field. I know it is possible to use custom fields, but I'd rather avoid that if possible just for continuity.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the validation rules.

Under your template, browse to your field definition item and you can select the validators in the `Validation Rules` section. There's a sample rule located here: `/sitecore/system/Settings/Validation Rules/Field Rules/Sample/Max Length 40`, which makes sure you have a max length of 40 characters. You could of course duplicate and alter this rule.

Comment: When I use this it throws a validation fail despite being significantly within the character limit? It fails with the sample.

Comment: I just checked it with the sample rule - 40 characters (and less) passes in my environment, >40 fails. Which fields have you added the validation rule to? I've tried the following multilistfields: Quick Action Bar and Validator Bar.

In your sample rule, does it have the following in the type field:
Sitecore.Data.Validators.FieldValidators.MaxLengthFieldValidator,Sitecore.Kernel
and in the Parameters field:
MaxLength=40?

Comment: Yeah thats exactly what it says, I'm trying to apply it to a description field for an item stored as a single-line text. I am literally putting in 10 characters and it is popping up with a "Maximum length of 40" popup and not allowing it to save.

Comment: Hmm. I don't get any issues with saving either - are you sure there's not another validation going on there apart from the sample rule? 
Can you double check for me that you set those rules on the field definition of the template, and not on the item itself, in the Validation Rules sections in there? I.e. add it to /sitecore/templates/User Defined/TestTemplate/Section/Test Field. One quick way of finding out if it's in the correct location is by NOT showing standard fields.

Comment: It is applied to the field "Decription" within the template, so I've opened the tree and selected the "item" for the field with the path as yo suggested. There is no other validation running at all.

Comment: I figured it out in the end. The validator had been edited and wasn't the sample one.

Answer (score 0):

You add custom field validator:

```cs
using Sitecore.Data.Validators;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

// DLL: "MySitecore.dll"

namespace MySitecore.Data.Validators.FieldValidators
{
    public class StringLengthValidator : StandardValidator
    {
        public const Int32 MaxStringLength = 40; // Change me

        protected override ValidatorResult Evaluate()
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(base.ControlValidationValue))
            {
                if (base.ControlValidationValue.Length > MaxStringLength)
                {
                    base.Text = base.GetText("The field '{0}' exceeds the maximum string length of {1}", new String[]{
                        base.GetFieldDisplayName(),
                        MaxStringLength
                    });
                    return base.GetFailedResult(ValidatorResult.Error);
                }
            }
            return ValidatorResult.Valid;
        }

        protected override ValidatorResult GetMaxValidatorResult()
        {
            return base.GetFailedResult(ValidatorResult.Error);
        }

        public override String Name
        {
            get { return String.Format("Must be {0} or fewer characters", MaxStringLength); }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, add an item that corresponds with that validator:

- In the Content Editor, navigate to `/sitecore/system/Settings/Validation Rules/Field Rules/Text`
- Add new item (inheriting from `/sitecore/templates/System/Validation/ValidationRule`)
- Populate the values

  - Title is the short title to show
  - Description is the helper text shown after the rule name
  - Type is the fully-qualified reference to your new validator. Using the above as an example, this would be:
    `MySitecore.Data.Validators.FieldValidators.StringLengthValidator, MySitecore`

Finally, go to your template, locate the field you want to add validation to and apply your new validator.